# Ethers.js: Error when calling symbol() on Maker (MKR) contract but no problem for other ERC-20 token contracts

Tags: solidity, erc-20, etherscan, ethers.js

I'm running into an issue using ethers for an address tracking app I'm building. Whenever I make a call using the generic ERC20 ABI I've written in my code (I am only needing to retrieve the symbol and the decimals from the token), for pretty much every token I've tested it works fine. However, for the Maker contract https://etherscan.io/address/0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2#code

calling symbol() is returning the following error:

`call revert exception (method="symbol()", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.3.0)`

I've recreated the issue I've encountered in this ethers codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/08bue?file=/src/App.js

Copy and paste this code into the sandbox (sorry, I don't want to create an account to make my own sandbox)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

// A Web3Provider wraps a standard Web3 provider, which is
// what Metamask injects as window.ethereum into each page
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
//mkr address (doesnt work)
const mkrAddress = "0x9f8F72aA9304c8B593d555F12eF6589cC3A579A2"
//weth address (works)
const wethAddress = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"

//abi I am using in my code
const ERC20_ABI = [
  // Read-Only Functions
  "function decimals() view returns (uint8)",
  "function symbol() view returns (string)",
];
//mkr abi from etherscan
const MKR_ABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"stop","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"owner_","type":"address"}],"name":"setOwner","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"},{"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"name_","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"setName","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"stopped","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"authority_","type":"address"}],"name":"setAuthority","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"push","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"},{"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"move","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"start","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"authority","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"guy","type":"address"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"},{"name":"guy","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"pull","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"symbol_","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Mint","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Burn","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"authority","type":"address"}],"name":"LogSetAuthority","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"LogSetOwner","type":"event"},{"anonymous":true,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"sig","type":"bytes4"},{"indexed":true,"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"foo","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"name":"bar","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"fax","type":"bytes"}],"name":"LogNote","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}]

const contract = new ethers.Contract(
  mkrAddress,
  ERC20_ABI,
  provider
);

const getSymbol = async () =>{
  let sym = await contract.symbol()
  console.log(sym)
}

getSymbol()

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Check console</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Looking at the console and the display, you can see the error. When declaring the contract object, if you swap the maker contract out for the weth contract I also included you can see it now functions fine. Maker is the only token I've run into this issue with so far out of many. I included the mkr ABI from etherscan and using this instead seems to fix the issue, however this is not practical for my app as I need a generic ABI to detect every possible token. I could hardcode in the mkr ABI when I detect the mkr contract address but this seems like a not so great fix, especially if this can happen with other tokens I'm unaware of. Is this issue due to something in the way the mkr contract was written that makes it different from most erc20 tokens, as far as its symbol? A call to decimals() works just fine. I'm relatively new to this type of development so any explanation or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maker token does not implement the *optional* parameters symbol and name
as proposed by `EIP-20`:

As you can see [here](https://github.com/makerdao/dss-vest/blob/4e04cec2607a6e59960ce8bd729666cfddc2f523/echidna/DSToken.sol#L197-L199), Maker uses bytes32 for symbol and name.

, where in the case of EIP-20 they are both [strings.](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20)

I would suggest you just check for bytes32 and strings when you try to get the name and symbol of a ERC20 token. That should cover most cases.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks for the help.